# Flowable deploy the flowable application on the Flowable UI

Tags: java, flowable

I have created a flowable application using spring boot and flowable API in eclipse. Now my requirement is to run the process from the Flowable UI. Is there any that we can deploy the existing application

[Flow able eclipse view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDnKh.png)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are referring to the flowable-task application. If you are creating your own Flowable application you would need to build your own UI.

An option would be to build your own custom jar (with the services that should be used by your service tasks) and then provide that jar to the classpath of the flowable-task application. If you are using Tomcat you can just drop your jar the `tomcat/libs` folder

Have a look at https://forum.flowable.org/t/use-of-flowable-ui-task-with-own-flowable-engine/2603/ and  https://forum.flowable.org/t/flowable-ui-and-springboot-integration/2610 as well

Comment: @Fiip I have tried to put the jar(fat jar with all dependency as when I just put plain jar it gives the error class not found) in  tomcat/lib but it is giving the error :org.flowable.common.engine.api.FlowableIllegalArgumentException: com.saurav.flowable_test.TestForm doesn't implement org.flowable.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate nor org.flowable.engine.impl.delegate.ActivityBehavior        Even though I have implemanted the org.flowable.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate. Can suggest any way I can resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to flowable-modeler and create app after that click on edit included models and add the your bpmn and close.

After that go to app and you can publish and download zip/bar after that you can deploy on admin portal.